# Android - Random android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, readonly

i published an app in Android Market which uses sqlite as database. The database is located in sdcard and i have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest. The problem is, the app works fine most of the time, but for some users, SQLiteExceptions occur:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE question SET count_taken = count_taken + 1, count_score = count_score + 0.0, last_taken_date = 1322106577 WHERE rowid = 1
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1874)
at com.testsstore.app.helper.DatabaseHelper.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.java:234)
```

I really want to find the root cause of this problem to fix it. Has anyone experienced this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This problem has got nothing to do with SD card / external storage. I've got my db's on internal storage and my users still report this exception.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am getting the same error randomly in my app.